# Grails Database Migration and Jenkins on Cloudbees

Tags: grails, jenkins, database-migration, cloudbees

I want to have a automatic deployment of my test system on every night to the dev@cloud system of cloudbees.

The problem is now that I use the dbm-update goal on grails and its trying to update the database from Jenkins. This is a problem because the com.cloudbees.jdbc.Driver is not available in this context. Only if the app is deployed to the test sytem.

Does somebody tried this already and can help me out with some tips how to solve or workaround this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `updateOnStart` flags in the plugin for your application in the test context,

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileNames = ['changelog.groovy']
```

This will run the migrations when your test application starts, making you not need to do a separate `dbm-update`. Since this uses the same JDBC drivers as your running application, it should work.

Comment: Thank you this is working. One question, what is happening when the database update is failing? I mean later when running a production system it would be good to have this part apart from the deployment to get the production database running beforehand and reacting on errors.

Comment: You should catch this when running your migrations by running dbm-update locally before committing. But if it fails, it will make your application not start up. Your CI would catch any failures during test, though.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the RUN console (https://run.cloudbees.com) - there you will find your MySQL settings

You can just use a standard MySQL JDBC driver to connect to the MySQL database from anywhere (including from DEV@cloud and your test cases).